# How to add text to an existing div with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, text, addition

I want to add text to an existing div, when I click the Button with the id #add. But this is not working.

Here my code:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#Add').click(function () {
    $('<p>Text</p>').appendTo('#Content');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="Content">
    <button id="Add">Add</button>
 </div>
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need to define the button text and have valid HTML for the button.   I would also suggest using `.on` for the click handler of the button

```js
$(function () {
  $('#Add').on('click', function () {
    $('<p>Text</p>').appendTo('#Content');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Content">
    <button id="Add">Add Text</button>
</div>
```

Also I would make sure the jquery is at the bottom of the page just before the closing `</body>` tag.  Doing so will make it so you do not have to have the whole thing wrapped in `$(function` but I would still do that.  Having your javascript load at the end of the page makes it so the rest of the page loads incase there is a slow down in your javascript somewhere.

Comment: The jquery `.replaceWith()` method removes content from the DOM and inserts new content in its place with a single call. `$( "div.second" ).replaceWith( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );` [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Answer (score 12):

Running example:

```js
//If you want add the element before the actual content, use before()
$(function () {
  $('#AddBefore').click(function () {
    $('#Content').before('<p>Text before the button</p>');
  });
});

//If you want add the element after the actual content, use after()
$(function () {
  $('#AddAfter').click(function () {
    $('#Content').after('<p>Text after the button</p>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Content">
<button id="AddBefore">Add before</button>
<button id="AddAfter">Add after</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your html is invalid `button` is not a null tag. Try

```
<div id="Content">
   <button id="Add">Add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do it in more easy way like by adding a function on button and on click we call that function for append.

```
<div id="Content">
<button id="Add" onclick="append();">Add Text</button>
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function append()
{
$('<p>Text</p>').appendTo('#Content');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy from My side:-

```
<html>
<head>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input").click(function() {
            $('<input type="text" name="name" value="value"/>').appendTo('#testdiv');
        });

    });
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="testdiv"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Add" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
  $('#Add').click(function () {
    $('<p>Text</p>').appendTo('#Content');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="Content">
    <button id="Add">Add<button>
 </div>
```