# How can I get Javascript to display text in html as I type?

Tags: javascript

I made a simple guess the letter game. I want to display the letters guessed in the html after I type them. What can I use to do that?

Comment: try put some example.

Comment: Can you [detect key press events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)?  Can you update HTML on the page?
  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this; perhaps quickest and easiest is with jQuery.

1. Include Jquery in your page
2. Make a div element and give it an ID.
3. After a letter is guessed/typed, use .appendTo(), .html(), .val(), or the like to add the guess to the list

[How to add text to an existing div with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581059/how-to-add-text-to-an-existing-div-with-jquery)

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

Comment: Thank you! That helped out a lot.