# Beginner JavaScript into HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to coding, I started taking a programming class a month ago and we were recently assigned our first project. I am trying to get my javascript code into my index.html. So far I have this in my html page:

```
<script src="/project1/prices.js" type='Javascript/text></script>`
```

My javascript page currently has this in it:

```
var price1Name = "Tickets for 18 and under";
var price2Name = "Tickets for 18 and over"; 
var price3Name = "T-shirt (all sizes)";
var price4Name = "Jackets (all sizes)"; 


var price1price = "$5.00";
var price2price = "$10.00";
var price3price = "$15.00";
var price4price = "$20.00";


document.write(price1Name);
document.write(price1price);
document.write(price2Name);
document.write(price2price);
document.write(price3Name);
document.write(price3price);
document.write(price4Name);
document.write(price4price);
```

All I am trying to do is input this code into my Html page so that I am able to display the items and their prices. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Thanks for your time, anything helps!

Comment: use jquery instead

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581059/how-to-add-text-to-an-existing-div-with-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add text to an existing div with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581059/how-to-add-text-to-an-existing-div-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your `script` tag has a couple errors

```
<script src="/project1/prices.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Changed that however nothing is still popping up on my HTML.

Comment: @kl next thing I'd do is verify the directory location on the js file (make sure it's actually being loaded)

Comment: Just did, it's in the same folder as my html

Comment: @kl in that case your src can just be `"prices.js"`

Comment: @snapjs changed that sa well, still not getting any text in my html

Comment: @kl can you update the question with your entire html file?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
//code
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> You can paste your JavaScript code between the script tags in the
>   body. This will allow you to insert JavaScript code into your HTML
>   page.